# samba 4.3.9 ntlm_auth: Memory allocation error (0xc0000017)

Tags: samba, samba4

System: Ubuntu 16.04 - samba Version 4.3.9-Ubuntu

```
-> # ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=VBA.LAN --username=[user] --password=[pw]
NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY: Memory allocation error (0xc0000017)
```

This happens after upgrade to 16.04. Is this a bugg? Don't find any more information in logs. Suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

I need this for freeradius connection to samba AD (http://deployingradius.com/documents/configuration/pap.html)

Comment: Filled bug: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing --domain=VBA.LAN to --domain=VBA fixed it!